# Enzyme: with shallow, redux store update does not trigger componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, enzyme

I'm having trouble testing a very specific use case of my React components. In this case, I have a component that dispatches an action on mount, and then dispatches another action after the results of the first dispatch come in.

The problem, I believe, comes down to enzyme's `shallow` method not calling `componentDidUpdate` in my component. I have reproduced the problem with the simplest code I could, and confirmed that the problem disappears if I use `mount` instead of `shallow`. However, [enzyme's documentation](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) says that since version 3, `shallow` does call React's lifecycle methods such as `componentDidUpdate`. And of course, I cannot use `mount` in my test because I don't want to mount the entire tree (in my case, that would mean loading my entire application).

Thus I wonder: is this a bug in enzyme, or I am missing something in my usage of that library?

Here's my code example:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';


const actions = {
    // This would fetch a resource on the network.
    getList: () => {},

    receiveList: list => {
        return {
            type: 'RECEIVE_LIST',
            list,
        };
    },

    // This would fetch a list of resources on the network.
    getObjects: () => {},
};


const reducer = (state = { list: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'RECEIVE_LIST':
            return { ...state, list: action.list };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};


class MyAppBase extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(actions.getList());
    }

    componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.list !== this.props.list) {
            this.props.dispatch(actions.getObjects(nextProps.list));
        }
    }

    render() {
        return null;
    }
}


const MyApp = connect(state => { return { list: state.list }; })(MyAppBase);



describe('<MyApp>', () => {
    it('fetches objects once list is received', () => {
        // Mock actions that call the network.
        sinon.stub(actions, 'getList');
        actions.getList.returns({type: 'whatever'});
        sinon.stub(actions, 'getObjects');
        actions.getObjects.returns({type: 'whatever'});

        // Create a redux store.
        const store = createStore(reducer);

        // Create the component.
        const wrapper = shallow(<MyApp store={store} />);

        // Verify that `componentDidMount` was called but not `componentDidUpdate`.
        expect(actions.getList.callCount).toEqual(1);
        expect(actions.getObjects.callCount).toEqual(0);

        // Dispatch an action that will change the redux store.
        store.dispatch(actions.receiveList([ 'aa', 'bb' ]));

        // Expect the `componentDidUpdate` method to be called.
        expect(actions.getObjects.callCount).toEqual(1);

        // This doesn't work, for some reason `componentDidUpdate` is never called.
    });
});
```

Package versions I use for this:

```
"react": "16.6.0",
"react-dom": "16.6.0",
"react-redux": "5.1.0",
"redux": "4.0.1",
"enzyme": "3.7.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.6.0",
"sinon": "7.1.0"
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have encountered the same problem. What's more, it seems to me that problem is bigger than just not calling `componentDidUpdate`. I tried triggering this method manually with `setProps()`, after dispatching action, and, although `cDU` was called, changes in store were still not reflected in component's props (when changes from `setProps()` were.

Answer (score 2):

**The "componentDidUpdate" method does not seem to be fully supported by Enzyme's "shallow" method.**

A `shallow` mounted component seems to only call `componentDidUpdate` following a call to `wrapper.setProps()`. It doesn't matter that the store is updated with new state, the wrapper is just not updated.

This can be confirmed by changing your test to do the following:

```
// Dispatch an action that will change the redux store.
store.dispatch(actions.receiveList([ 'aa', 'bb' ]));

// Will print '[]'
console.log(wrapper.instance().props.list);

// Create a new wrapper with the current store:
const wrapper2 = shallow(<MyApp store={store} />);

// Will print '['aa', 'bb']'
console.log(wrapper2.instance().props.list)
```

A workaround would be to call `setProps` after the `store.dispatch` (or preferably just use `mount` instead of `shallow`, if it is feasible):

```
// Dispatch an action that will change the redux store.
store.dispatch(actions.receiveList([ 'aa', 'bb' ]));

// Manually cause componentDidUpdate to trigger
wrapper.setProps({
  list: ['aa', 'bb']
});
```

Additionally, `componentDidUpdate` can be triggered by the `simulate` method for a click or a change on a button or input.